start nodejs server in debug mode with npm script
I want a npm script that starts my index.js server in debug mode. I will run this script from outside the folder of the server with a tasks.json command.
My last attempt:
"scripts": { "debug": "nodemon --inspect index.js" },
It wrote a message, but the breakpoints are not working
When I start debugging by opening "javascript debug terminal" and starting the server, or by clicking the debug text on the top of the npm scripts, the breakpoints work.

I want to achieve this with one command without clicking around in VS.
